# matplotlib can't work in OS X with error ' TKApplication is implemented in both'

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I am using the mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.1, I have installed matplotlib using `pip install matplotlib.`

I tried a simple application as below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4], [1,4,9,16], 'ro')
plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])
plt.show()
```

the python application runs and show the window, but without any graph. The command line just gave me a error saying:

```
Class TKApplication is implemented in both /Users/xisizhe/anaconda/lib/libtk8.5.dylib and /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
 Class TKMenu is implemented in both /Users/xisizhe/anaconda/lib/libtk8.5.dylib and /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Class TKContentView is implemented in both /Users/xisizhe/anaconda/lib/libtk8.5.dylib and /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Class TKWindow is implemented in both /Users/xisizhe/anaconda/lib/libtk8.5.dylib and /System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Tk. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

How can I choose one of the two ?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem so my solution was to just not use Tk for the backend after not being able to resolve the issue quickly.  Looks like a periodic issue when using Anaconda based on the many threads I found while looking for a solution.

I used this to find available backends

```
python -c "import matplotlib; print matplotlib.rcsetup.all_backends"
```

Then added the following to `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` to use the Qt4 backend

```
backend:Qt4Agg
```